# Displaying data table using grid/list view using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to using vue.js, and actively learning javascript at the same time. I would like to display a data table in the list view and I have folder images to display for the grid view. I'm just having trouble with getting it to display. If anyone can offer help, I'd be really thankful for that.
Have a great day!

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Justin read the vuejs document first, after that you cant figureout post here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try yourself then if you cant figureout post Stackoverflow Justin

Please read the document properly then start.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Inside Template :

```
<table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" >
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Code</th>
  </thead>
  <tr v-for="(item, index) in paymentList" :key="index">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.mobile }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Inside Script :

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      paymentList: [
        { name: "gopal", mobile: "123456", code: "ABC123" },
        { name: "krishnan", mobile: "147852", code: "ABC258" },
        { name: "varun", mobile: "369852", code: "ABC147" }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```